# TCP connection between two raspberry pis error, “No such host exists”

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

This is my first C++ project where I am communicating via TCP and I used this client/server method from [Here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm). I changed the hostname on the pi that acts as the server and I believe that I am running the client program with the right hostname and port, however it keeps throwing me the error "No such host exists" even though they are on the same network. The client and server programs work if I run them on the same pi.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the server and the client code?

Comment: does it work with `ip:port`?

Comment: check that you can ping and telnet